# Reliable and universal account recovery

Tags: private-key, recovery, smart-contract-wallets

I am producing kinda salary system.

If somebody loses an account, he or she loses the salary for his entire lifetime!!

So need some account recovery.

First I wanted to use my own recovery system with BrightID to confirm identity of the person who lost his private key. But BrigthID allows to recover by just two trusted connections (friends). That's too bad for an account with money associated to it, two fake friends and the salary goes.

Next, I may require (or advise very strongly, but people are not following advice...) to use a smart wallet with recovery for the salary account, not just a wallet.

Which smart wallet to choose? Or to create my own smart wallet? What if people will want to change the set of features (e.g. the recovery procedure) for the smart wallet? use upgradeable by global voting smart contract for the wallets? any other ideas?

I want the wallet to be accessible both desktop and mobile.

I want it to work for 100 years! (unless the civilization dies)

Comment: Another way would be to use GoodDollar Identity contract for recovery, but that's a centralized system and it _can_ be hijacked.

Comment: This is normally addressed using MultiSig recovery (several delegated users together can recover the key). It's all about how to choose these designated users, but I guess that within an organisation, they should be either HR / Managers / etc.

Comment: @SergiJuanati Read the question again. I said that I didn't know how to choose the particular smart wallet for multisig recovery.

Answer (score 0):

I've realized what to do.

Account recovery will be important in the future. So, let future voting decides it.

For now, I could just set a voting system for the community to assign some smart contract for recovery in the future.